# Check for specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a String is in certain pattern.

for example i want to check is a String matches the pattern: 2012-02-20.

I.E: xxxx-xx-xx when x is a number.

Is it possible? someone said regular expressions.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: If you are trying to parse date, you should use `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse the date.

Comment: Possible? Yes, that's one of the simpler problems that are solvable with turing machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`

for checking use:

```
yourString.matches(regexString);
```

Comment: This anserws OPs question, but does not solve his problem. As it's obviously a date he is looking for, yours will match `2012-20-20`, which is clearly not a valid date.

Comment: You can find good regexps for date. People sometimes avoiding the exceptions for checking even if it does the job, this will provide an exceptionless solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) parse method:

```
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

boolean matchesDateFormat(String date)
{
    try
    {
        format.parse(date);
        return true;
    }
    catch(ParseException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you later go on to parse the date anyway then you can skip this and just try to parse it.

Comment: This is not sufficient. SimpleDateFormat would just blindly accept invalid dates such as `2013-02-29`. There is also no guarantee that the whole string matches the format specified.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to test if the date string is a valid date, better use `SimpleDateFormat` to check. don't use regex for that validation, how about month is 13? date is 50? leap years?

some example:

```
public boolean isValidDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        df.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my comment on the other answer. Your code is not sufficient. It will happily parse `2013-02-29` or `2013-02-28JSfksdjfksf` without giving any error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the String follow the exact format of 4 digits, a dash `-`, 2 digits, a dash `-` and 2 digits with @burning_LEGION's regex. However, it doesn't check whether the String represents a valid date. You can specify `9999-99-99` and it will pass the validation.

Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the proper method to check that the String is a valid date and it follows a given format of representation. SimpleDateFormat, apart from [formatting a date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29), can also be used to parse Date from String: [`parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).

By default, SimpleDateFormat is **lenient**, which means it will allow nonsensical dates such as `2013-025-234` to pass. Use [`setLenient(boolean lenient)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to `false` will solve this problem.

However, another problem is that it will also ignore any garbage data that is after a valid date (e.g. `2012-03-23garbage#$%$#%`). Setting lenient doesn't solve this problem. We need to check the last position with `parse(String, ParsePosition)` method.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// Make the parsing strict - otherwise, it is worse than regex solution
dateFormatter.setLenient(false); 

Date date = null;
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);

date = dateFormatter.parse(inputString, pos);

if (date != null && pos.getIndex() == inputString.length()) {
    // These 3 points are ensured:
    // - The string only contains the date.
    // - The date follows the format strictly.
    // - And the date is a valid one.
} else {
    // Valid date but string contains other garbage
    // Or the string has invalid date or garbage
}
```

`SimpleDateFormat` will allow `2013-1-5` to pass, which I think is a reasonable leniency. If you don't want this, you can do a check against the regex before plugging the String into the `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following code:

```
public void test() {
    String REG_EXP = "(\\d{4}-[0,1]?\\d{1}-[0,1,2,3]?\\d{1})"; //yyyy-mm-dd formate this can not check boundary condition something like this... 1981-02-30 
    String REG_EXP1 = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})"; // if u just want xxxx-xx-xx where x is number 
    String input = "date1 1981-09-06 wrong date 9999-22-22 date2 1981-9-09 date3 1981-11-1 date4"; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REG_EXP); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); 
    while (matcher.find()) { 
       System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```